# How to filter columns by criteria one by one (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on the survey data and be asked to extract the data with the criteria for each columns.(i.e. the value of column "Unnamed: 277" in df has to be TRUE and so as column 'Unnamed: 308'and so on till column 'Unnamed: 457') I did the code below but felt not practical at all. Is there any better way to do this by Python?
Thank you in advance.
[this link is the df has been returned to a boolean type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hLZq.png)

```
df1 = df[df["Unnamed: 277"] & (df['Unnamed: 308']) & 
(df['Unnamed: 311']) & (df['Unnamed: 314']) & (df['Unnamed: 317']) & 
(df['Unnamed: 320']) & (df['Unnamed: 3267']) & (df['Unnamed: 3312']) 
& (df['Unnamed: 3367']) & (df['Unnamed: 3412']) & (df['Unnamed: 3467']) 
& (df['Unnamed: 3512']) & (df['Unnamed: 3567'])
& (df['Unnamed: 3612']) & (df['Unnamed: 3667']) & (df['Unnamed: 3712']) 
& (df['Unnamed: 400']) & (df['Unnamed: 457'])]
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete verifiable example - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you wish to filter by a given list of columns which *all* must be `True`, you can use vectorised functionality on a Boolean dataframe / array.

Specifically, you need [`pd.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) over `axis=1` to ensure your logic is applied row-wise.

```
L = ['Unnamed: 277', 'Unnamed: 308', 'Unnamed: 311', ...]

df_filtered = df[df[L].all(1)]
```